# WordPress change post archive link for all in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the archive link like below.

http://localhost/wordpress/2018/03/ => http://localhost/wordpress/arr/2018/03/

I have changed the post link as below.

```
function append_query_string($url, $post, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/arr/') !== false) {
        if ($post->post_type == 'post') {
            //$url = home_url(user_trailingslashit("arr/$post->post_name"));
            $url = str_replace(home_url(), "", $url);
            $url = home_url(user_trailingslashit("arr$url"));
        }
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3);
```

Please guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Need to use the **day_link** filter in WordPress.

```
function prepend_archive_string($url, $post, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/arr/') !== false) {
             $url = str_replace(home_url(), "", $url);
            $url = home_url(user_trailingslashit("arr$url"));
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('day_link', 'prepend_archive_string', 10, 3);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize permalinks uner Settings -> Permalinks in wordpress.
If you select the custom permalink option , you can set something like:
localhost/wordpress/%postname%/%year%/%monthnum%/

Comment: Hi @Eva. But I want to change only when the URL contains "arr".